# why does this query return three rows of the same answer

Tags: neo4j, cypher

'm having trouble understanding why this query is returning this result.
Node (A) only exists in my graph once but shows up three times in the result 
What I want is a total count of each outer node + the (A) node - in this case, that value should be 4.

Here is a link to the console graph: http://console.neo4j.org/r/btmdfi

```
MATCH (n)-[r]-(m)
WHERE n.label = 'A'
WITH n, m, collect (Distinct m.size) as sizes, collect (Distinct m.weight) as weights, collect (Distinct m.color) as colors
WITH n, sizes, weights, colors, count ( m.size) as size_ct, count ( m.weight) as weight_ct, count ( m.color) as color_ct
WITH n, sizes, weights, colors, sum( size_ct + weight_ct + color_ct) as count_n
RETURN n.label
```

---

I wanted to add a second part to the query that would search for other nodes that also have a label, then compare the types of nodes (m.weight, m.size, m.color) and count of those types to (A) node's values. 
so output would look like:

```
n.label  count_match(r) m.weight m.size m.color 
A           4             heavy    small  red 
B           2/4           light    large  red 
C           3/4           light    small  red
```

Answer (score 1):

In your graph (according to your console), you have three relationships coming from "A" and, as such, your query will match three paths.

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "outer node".

Answer (score 1):

The query:

```
MATCH (n:label)-[r]->(m)
WHERE n.label = 'A'
RETURN n.label, count(r)
```

Will return one row, with 'A' in the first column and the number 3 in the second, for the three nodes connected to 'A'. If you are looking to get a 'group by' effect like this, then you cannot return both n and m in the same WITH statement like above.

It is also a little unusual to see chained WITH statements with nothing between them. Not sure what you were planning there. Perhaps some more explanation on what you wanted the complete query (with all the collect() and WITH) was intended to do?

A query like:

```
MATCH (n:label)-[r]->(m)
WHERE n.label = 'A'
RETURN n.label, count(r),
    collect(m.weight), collect(m.size), collect(m.color)
```

gives a little more information. Perhaps this is heading towards what you are after?

Comment: The second query is exactly what I was looking for. I guess I just don't quite understand the purpose of WITH statements - I was using them to define variables(or what I thought was to keep them defined) throughout the query.

Comment: I added more in the edit of what I am ultimately after

Answer (score 0):

Your query returns `n.label`. `n.label` is defined early in your query as 'A'. That should make it obvious why it's returning 'A' three times.

Let's break down a simple query that just returns 4:

```
MATCH (n)-[r]-(m)
WHERE n.label = 'A'
RETURN count(m) + 1
```

Here we are asking Neo4j to return all of the nodes (m) that are connected to A (n). Then, we count them and add 1 to include the A node. This query returns the nodes `:size 4`, `:color red`, and `:weight 4`.

Is that what you wanted? As others have posted, it's not clear what you mean by "outer nodes." If you could name or provide a list of "outer nodes" I can revise my sample query to retrieve the information you want.